# Bunch of Errors using Pandas on Demand Forecast Script from Github

Tags: python, pandas, forecast

i just started with python due to I need some forecast algorithms for electricity demand.
However I managed to understand some basics of Python and used the script "DemandForecast" jingw2 https://github.com/jingw2/demand_forecast
In particular I run/ran the tpa_lstm.py file.

Since the script was published I assume Pandas made some changes. This results in bunch of error messages I am not able to solve.
I would be more than happy if someone can help me out.

This is the report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py", line 1008, in _cmp_method
    other = self._validate_comparison_value(other)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py", line 542, in _validate_comparison_value
    raise InvalidComparison(other)
pandas.core.arrays.datetimelike.InvalidComparison: 2014-01-01

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\d\PycharmProjects\01_Learning\main.py", line 236, in <module>
    data = data.loc[(data["date"] >= date(2014, 1, 1)) & (data["date"] <= date(2014, 3, 1))]
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 70, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py", line 60, in __ge__
    return self._cmp_method(other, operator.ge)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 5623, in _cmp_method
    res_values = ops.comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 269, in comparison_op
    res_values = op(lvalues, rvalues)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 70, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py", line 60, in __ge__
    return self._cmp_method(other, operator.ge)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py", line 1010, in _cmp_method
    return invalid_comparison(self, other, op)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\invalid.py", line 34, in invalid_comparison
    raise TypeError(f"Invalid comparison between dtype={left.dtype} and {typ}")
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date
```

I use Pandas 1.4.2 and Python 3.10.4.

Thank you very much!
TR

Comment: If you look at the `requirements.txt` file in that repo you can see the verions of libraries that it worked with. That references `pandas==0.25.3`, which was a _very_ long time ago and there have been a lot of changes and deprications since then. If you truly must use that package, your best bet is to set up an environment with the packages installed to the versions listed in that requirements file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
data = data.loc[(data["date"] >= date(2014, 1, 1)) & (data["date"] <= date(2014, 3, 1))]
```

by

```
data = data.loc[(data["date"] >= datetime.strptime('2014-1-1', '%Y-%m-%d')) & (data["date"] <= datetime.strptime('2014-3-1', '%Y-%m-%d'))]
```

in your tpa_lstm.py file (line 235)